# How to pass value from MVC view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
//Here is my View
 @using 
 (Html.BeginForm("SearchUser", "User", FormMethod.Get))
  {
      <input type="text" id="keyText">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
  }
```

In my controller I am having a method for SearchUser -

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUser ([FromQuery] string keyText)
{
    SearchUsersCommandAsync command = new SearchUsersCommandAsync
    {
        Key = keyText
    };

    var response = await new SearchUsersHandler(_db).Handle(command);
    return View("Detail", response);
}
```

However when i receive the request KeyText always null. Whats wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Your input needs a `name` attribute - `name="keyText"` in order to send a its value to the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="keyText" name="KeyText">
```

add the name attribute to your input with same name as what you have use parameter in your controller method